# How to optimally set up a monitor to be as well calibrated as possible when used as a liveview finder?

Tags: color-management, display-calibration

If you want the most precise color reproduction from a computer monitor, you calibrate it. But calibration mostly changes the PC, not the monitor, apart from the selection of basic color profile and brightness/contrast.

Is there any standard how to set up a monitor connected directly to the HDMI output of a DSLR or DSLM, used as a viewfinder or review device - or is it "just set the color profile to sRGB, turn off all "picture enhancement" options and pray hard"?

Assumption: Camera is set up to use sRGB.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this once, took some fiddling around with monitor settings.

Basically, I took a photo in RAW at correct exposure and printed it without editing. Took that photo to my screen and adjusted my screen settings until they where as close to the photo as possible.

I didn't want to use the camera because the JPG output on the screen would not give true colors, lights and shades of the photo that the print direct from an unedited RAW can.

The screen then gave me a closer actual result than the back of the camera, so when I plugged my camera into the screen, I would use the screen to check a shot instead of the back of the camera.

Comment: Yes, indeed..  You could simply open it in a program like Lightroom or Photoshop, or any other program than can open a RAW file. If you don't have a editing program to edit RAW files you could install install the codex on your computer that will allow you to view and print RAW files on your computer as if they were JPG files. For example, for Nikon, you can find the NEF codex here: https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/170/NEF_Codec.html or for Canon cameras, you can find the canon codex here: https://www.canon.ie/support/consumer_products/software/canon-raw-codec.aspx.